# About item in listview for app c# in windows store

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps

How I can put inside an item of a listview another listview???, that is to say a listview inside a listview...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look on the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

i would say to move for Windows Phone 8 . Windows Phone 8 apps and Windows 8 share alot of code but when it comes to UI they are different. So in Windows Phone 8 it is common to user scrool veritcally and if you want horizontal motion it is better to use Panorama or Pivot.

Comment: I'm trying to make a user control for Window 8 RT.
What I do is actually a ListView grouped by one or more columns, so had thought of a ListView within a ListView within a ListView ..... and so on ....
What is your advice for doing this??